# Assign strings from a string array to various string variables

Tags: java, arrays, string

what I want to do:

I want to extract every string from a string array to a different string variable.

Outputting this to the console is no problem of course, just iterate over the array.

But when it comes to assigning each value to a different variable, I dont get any further right now. All I found online were suggestions on how to concatenate each index of the array. That is not what I want. I had a similar solution for ints some time ago, but I cannot come up with it right now.

```
int answerPackagerCounter = 0;
String answerPackager = "answer" + answerPackagerCounter;

String answer0 = "";
String answer1 = "";
String answer2 = "";
String answer3 = "";

boolean correct0 = false;
boolean correct1 = false;
boolean correct2 = false;
boolean correct3 = false;

for(int k = 0; k < answers.size(); k++ ){
    answerPackager = answers.get(k);
}
```

Of course this does not work, since each time `answerPackager` is overwritten. I'm quite sure not much is missing here, but I can't see it right now.

Any input is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I want to extract every string from a string array to a different string variable."*  Why?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Can you briefly explain why would you extract each value to a different variable. May be there is a better solution to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: You could generate a .java file from your array, compile it through a system call and then load the resulting jar :)

Comment: The strings are used to be displayed in a Unity Game. Therefore I do need to access them one by one. But since the array will not be bigger than 4 items at any time, user2418306 idea will actually help me. Its actually the easiest solution, hehe. Thanks anyhow!

Comment: @N30 Unity can be programmed in Java?

Comment: @isnot2bad hehe, no. But the server side extension for SmartFoxServer is written in Java. Unity can use various languages, most common are probably c# and ActionScript

Answer (score 1):

What I've read is that a Map is probably the best way to go.  Where the key can be treated as your separate variable and the value of each key is the value.

You probably would want to create an string array of answer & correct variables that will hole answer0, answer1, etc... & correct0, correct1, etc...  That way you can avoid hardcoding

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] answers = new String[] { "Blah1", "Blah2", "Blah3", "Blah4" };
    String[] correct = new String[] { "false", "true", "false", "false" };

    Map<String, String> answersCorrect = new HashMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        answersCorrect.put("answer" + i, answers[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < correct.length; i++) {
        answersCorrect.put("correct" + i, correct[i]);
    }

    // Keys are not stored in order of setting
    for (String key : answersCorrect.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + key + " Value: " + answersCorrect.get(key));
    }

    System.out.println("");

    // Direct usage
    System.out.println(answersCorrect.get("answer0") + " " + answersCorrect.get("correct0"));
}
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about making two arrays, `String[] answer = new String[4]; Boolean[] correct= new Boolean[4];`

Better, create a class like this:

```
public Class Answers {

  private String[] answer = new String[4];
  private Boolean[] correct= new Boolean[4];


... Usuals getters and setters...


}
```